# Android java append n characters to string

Tags: java, android, string, append, string.format

I would like to append "0" string when an int is lower than 5. I have tried this

```
if(allItems_filtered.results(i).min_sale_unit_price.length() < 5){
   calc = 5 - allItems_filtered.results(i).min_sale_unit_price.length();
   min_sale_unit_price = String.format("%0" + calc + "d", allItems_filtered.results(i).min_sale_unit_price);
}
```

int `calc` is the amount of "0" it has to append in front of the `min_sale_unit_price` string

Which returns this error:

```
%d can't format java.lang.String arguments
```

Which is quite self explaining but I do not know how to the the same but then to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is telling you that you are trying to format a String, but `%d` is refering to an int, you need to convert the String to int an it will work. Also you don't need to calculate how many zeros you need, if you use `%05d` it will automatically fill the number till it's length isn't 5

```
min_sale_unit_price = String.format("%05d", Integer.valueOf(allItems_filtered.results(i).min_sale_unit_price));
```

Take for an example

```
Log.d("123?", String.format("%05d", 123));
```

Will print out

```
00123
```

If you take a number that is larger in size than five, it will not append anything

```
Log.d("123?", String.format("%05d", 123456));
```

Will result

```
123456
```

Comment: Alright I have tried this and doesn't return errors, but it also doesn't append the "0"? I've checked and the `int calc` is actually correct value.

Comment: Use %05d directly, your logic for calculating is wrong. You don't need to calculate even

Comment: Ah yes indeed, I thought it worked a bit different but it now does exactly what I want. Thank you for your time and help!